# How to upload a large file to a blob in Azure

Tags: azure

I need to upload a large file ( >6 MB) to a blob in windows Azure. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I use azure storage explorer for that

http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

more than 30 MB without problem

Comment: very usefull application :-) lots of great tools on codeplex :-)

Comment: you can also admin Tables and Queues. It's awesome

Answer (score 0):

Try this new tool I saw (in a deleted answer):

http://www.vic.ms/windows-azure/blob-transfer-utility/

it offers some features like queueing and parallel operations.

Comment: Just FYI; the reason that 'answer' was deleted was because it was spammed by that user multiple times to many different questions, all without disclosing that it was that person's own website.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I realize that.  It was still a good relevant answer to this question as it offers some features like queueing and parallel operations.